# How to use port forwarding on Server?

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to create a server that works on different wifi networks, and I heard from someone that I need to use port forwarding. Is this something I implement in my code as well as set up on the router? Also how do I set it up on my router? I posted my code below since I don't know if it'll be needed or not.

**Server**

```
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[1];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, port);
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily,
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
System.Console.WriteLine("Socket running on port " + port);
serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
System.Console.WriteLine("Accepting Connections");
System.Console.WriteLine(ipAddr);

serverSocket.Listen(10);
while (true)
{
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
    Thread t = new Thread(() => Login.login(clientSocket));
    System.Console.WriteLine("Client accepted.");
}
```

**Client**

```
System.Console.WriteLine("attempting to connect");
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
System.Console.WriteLine("tesinft3");
clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), port);
System.Console.WriteLine("tesinft4");
System.Console.WriteLine("Connected to Server");
```

Comment: Portforwarding is typically set up with the ISP. It's usually a concern for the host of the server, not the developer. Take for example, Python's SimpleHTTPServer or Node's http server

Comment: Unless the ISP is blocking the client network's ability to port forward, it's done on the router level. This process is different for every router. If you need to use it, you should look up your personal router's process of port forwarding. You will not need to account for it in code.

Comment: @user1538301 this is just wrong. You set up port-forwarding on your router, not through the ISP.

Comment: @TheBatman sure, ultimately the point is it's not the developers concern. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @user1538301 it definitely can be the developers concern. If this is a personal project then who else's concern would it be?

Comment: @TheBatman Well... the developer and the host are the same in that case... it's still not the developer's concern.

Comment: @TheBatman "It's as good as true, it is therefore true" - a user

Comment: @TheBatman If you want an example of portforwarding being the developer's concern, you should probably look at software.. that does port forwarding. An HTTP Server's (and therefore its developer) should not be concerned with port forwarding. But again, thanks for your info. Please keep the discourse meaningful. And FWIW, while you pointed out a mistake I made, you didn't do much to guide the OP or answer his question, in fact it almost sounds like you're recommending he go ahead and add portforwarding to his code. (Which is wrong)

Comment: No, I recommend he set up port forwarding on his router, considering, you know, that's how you do port forwarding.

Comment: @user1538301 I am here so OP doesn't think the incorrect information you are dropping here is accurate.

Comment: @user1538301 No, I don't think `portforwarding is an HTTP server application concern`. Its a networking concern. If you really want this to stop then stop saying incorrect things.

Comment: @TheBatman we agree then. Good day.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to do anything codewise.

Port forwarding is a Networking operation. Your server (meaning your program, not the machine) listens on a particular port or set of ports.

When the request reaches the host's network, Network Address Translation is applied in order to forward the request to a different host/port.

It is the device that is providing the Network Address Translation function that needs to be configured to make this happen and how it's done varies on the device/vendor, but generally speaking, it shouldn't be hard to figure out. It will be under "Networking" "NAT" or "Port Forwarding".

Comment: So how would I set it up? Is there a settings application somewhere for the router? And if so how do I access it?

Comment: @Andrewbandrew05 I have already answered this (see last paragraph above). While the setup is somewhat trivial, it is clear you are not well versed on these things so my advice is to find someone who knows Networking and let him/her do it for you or you will only end up causing security breaches or even worse, screwing up your router's configuration. There is no "exact guide" to how to do it. It depends on the type of router you have.

Comment: I am not very well versed in Networking, the only experience I have is with a basic local chat server using Python. I will get my router model number and see what I can find. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Andrewbandrew05: Good luck and don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you!